# RSpec - losing post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

looks like I am losing 'San Francisco' at the start of the Update test in this example - not sure why - when I do a puts response.body at the end the Post Test everything looks ok - here is my flights_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'flight'

RSpec.describe FlightsController, type: :controller  do

   render_views
   let(:flight0) { Flight.create(:destination => "Las Vegas") }

      it "Get Test" do
        puts 'Get Test'
        get :index, :format => :json
        puts "Body = " + response.body
        expect(response.body).to include('Las Vegas')
     end

     it "Post Test" do
       puts 'Post Test'
       post :create, :flight => {:destination => "San Francisco"}
       puts "Post status:" + response.status.to_s
       expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:flight))
       redirect_to(response.headers['Location'])
       get :index, :format => :json
       puts "Body = " + response.body
       expect(response.body).to include("San Francisco")
    end

    it "Update Test" do
        puts 'Delete Test'
        get :index, :format => :json
        puts "Body = " + response.body
        expect(response.body).to include("San Francisco")
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec assumes that you are writing each test to be independent of the other tests. However, the way you have it here, `Update Test` relies on `Post Test` to create the data it needs. RSpec automatically undoes any changes you made between each test. You can think of each `it` block as resetting everything back to the initial state.

A quick fix would be to simply aim the delete at the Las Vegas object instead since this flight is already being recreated for each test because of the `let` statement:

```
it "Update Test" do
    puts 'Delete Test'
    get :index, :format => :json
    puts "Body = " + response.body
    expect(response.body).to include("Las Vegas")
    # rest of your test
end
```

Also I just would note that you may run into issues with the `let` statement because it is lazily instantiated, meaning it may not actually create a Las Vegas `flight` until you actually try to use the `flight0` variable in your test. You can fix that by simply adding a bang to the end, like this `let!(:flight_0) {}`.

Comment: Since there is no need to reference `flight_0` anywhere, a `before` block might be more idiomatic.

Comment: @AndyWaite given the code here I agree with that, but I personally usually just set up with a `let` or `let!` statement anyway in case I end up needing to reference it. For example, if the OP decides to use something like Factory_Girl to create `Flight` objects, then being able to reference said object in the test will be helpful since hard-coding "Las Vegas" won't work anymore; it would need to be something like:

`expect response.body).to include(flight_0.destination)`